# Ubuntu Partition

Tags: dual-boot

Why should I use logical partition rather than primary?

```bsh
def dual_boot(x):
    for x in dual_boot():
        if x is <= 4:
            print("select primary partition ")
        else:
            print("select logical parition")
dual_boot(4)
```

I have just written this code because my question was not according to Ubuntu standards.

Ignore the code. Thanks

Comment: Related [Should I choose primary or logical, when I use UEFI + GPT to install Ubuntu 16.04 with custom partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109143/should-i-choose-primary-or-logical-when-i-use-uefi-gpt-to-install-ubuntu-16-0)

Comment: Instead of padding your question with junk code, it would be more useful to include relevant details such as your installation type, any existing partition layout etc.

Comment: @steeldriver if you have the answer to my question ti will appreciate it.

Comment: When you use gpt, which you should, all partitions are primary (in effect). Only 35 year old MBR had primary & logical and Microsoft has required vendors to use UEFI/gpt since 2012. https://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr